# mysqli SELECT query not working, for unknown reason

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is my php for connecting to a database and querying the table "userActivityTime", in which there is one row. I am not having trouble connecting to the database (i.e. no errors), but my query is not working, and despite looking all over the internet, I cannot figure out why. Hoping you all can help. Thanks so much in advance!

```
<?php

// ESTABLISH TABLE AND COLUMN NAMES

$mysqli = new mysqli("*****", "****", "*****", "****");

// MAKE SURE CONNECTION SUCCEEDED

if ($mysqli_connection->connect_error) {
    echo "Not connected, error: " . $mysqli_connection->connect_error;
    exit();
} else {
    echo "connected";
}

$query = "SELECT 'userDailyTime' FROM 'userActivityTime'";
if ($mysqli->query($query)) {
    echo $mysqli->error;
}


exit();

?>
```

Comment: If you truly got no errors, then this code would do nothing, so it would be impossible for it to "not work". Could you [edit] your question to be clearer about what result you got?

Comment: 'userActivityTime' is a string

Answer (score 2):

use back-ticks if necessary not single quotes:

```
SELECT `userDailyTime` FROM `userActivityTime`
```

or just

```
SELECT userDailyTime FROM userActivityTime
```

**Edit:**

An example from the internet, worm your stuff into the concept.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: OP is also using the wrong variable `$mysqli_connection`

Comment: dang Fred missed ya, half a month

Comment: I have tried it without quotes and it doesn't work even then.

Comment: clean up the connection variable as mentioned

Comment: @DrewPierce I was on vacation for 2 weeks. Much needed ;-)

Comment: I cleaned up the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put the table and column names in quotes. You are telling it to echo `$mysqli->error` when the query is successful (prepend it with an exclamation mark) . Also, you create `$mysqli` then refer to it as `$mysqli_connection`, so I am not sure how your code works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

// ESTABLISH TABLE AND COLUMN NAMES

$mysqli = new mysqli("*****", "****", "*****", "****");

// MAKE SURE CONNECTION SUCCEEDED

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Not connected, error: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    return false;
} else {
    echo "connected";
}

$query = "SELECT userDailyTime FROM userActivityTime";
if (!$mysqli->query($query)) {
    echo $mysqli->error;
}
return true;

?>
```